# Синхронизация между серверами

Tags: c#, .net, синхронизация

Имеется 3 инстанса "в облаке". На двух из них установлены веб-приложения, которые обрабатывают большое количество запросов в секунду (приложения идентичны). На 3м сервере установлено некое хранилище данных (не MSSQL), с которым работают веб-приложения (читают и записывают данные). Каким образом организовать синхронизацию между веб-приложениями, которые работают с одним источником данных?

Приложения работают на "виндовых инстансах", источник данных развернут на линуксе.

*Апдейт1*

**Одна** из проблем: оба инстанса получают однотипные запросы, в рамках которых есть некий ключ. В случае, когда это случается одновременно, код одновременно проверяет, существует ли в источнике данных запись с таким ключем и оба получают отрицательный ответ. После чего оба предпринимают решение по добавлении такой записи (такая логика), в следствии чего появляются дубликаты.

Я полностью отдаю себе отчет в архитектурных проблемах данного решения и не я был автором, но переделки займут слишком много усилий и времени, которого, как обычно, нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если такое понятие, как транзакция не чуждо Вашему источнику данных, то не вижу особых проблем. В противном случае я бы наверное попробовал заставить один инстанс только записывать данные, а второй работать в режиме read-only, чем фактически избавил бы себя от проблем с синхронизацией.

Comment: К сожалению ни транзакции ни разделение обязанностей не подходит.

Comment: @mister, в любом случае нужно будет реализовать либо транзакции, либо разделение обязанностей, иначе никак. Хотя, конечно, еще можно забить на консистентность данных :)

Comment: Данный ответ мне не походит, но по факту он правильный и других вариантов я просто не нашел.

Comment: Приидется переделывать все под корень.